"between" two countries
Does the following sentence make sense?
"My friend was charged with smuggling drugs between Spain and Portugal."
I want to say from one country to another, but don't seem to find the best way to phrase it.

Nitpick, but "charged with" is usually followed by the legal term for the charge as applied by the relevant court. "Charged for" can be used more broadly.

@the-baby-is-you While it’s true that charged with is often followed by a more legal term, I don’t see anything unnatural or unusual about ‘charged with smuggling drugs’ (a quick Google search shows it’s commonly enough used in newspaper articles as well). To me at least, charge for is not a prepositional verb like charge with is; it’s just intransitive charge followed by a PP headed by for (indicating a reason, as in ‘berated/rewarded/thrown out for doing X'), so the meaning is ever so slightly different, describing why he was charged, rather than what he was charged with.


My friend was charged with smuggling drugs between Spain and Portugal.

would mean the smuggling may be two-way and conducted multiple times.   If we mean a one-way smuggling, we could say
My friend was charged with smuggling drugs from Spain to Portugal.
